# How can I xor a string character with an int in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, xor, rc4-cipher

I'm trying to create a Python Ciphersaber 2 implementation since those that I've found on the net appear to produce gibberish. During the deciphering, I need to be able to xor a single character of a string with a keystream that is represented by integer values, and then cast that result back into a string character. Please note I am entirely new to Python so disregard my awful failures.

Things I've tried so far:

`plaintext[i] = ord(msg[i] ^ keystream[i]
 plaintext[i] = str(plaintext[i])` which resulted in integer values

and

`plaintext[i] = ord(msg[i] ^ keystream[i]
 plaintext[i] = chr(plaintext[i])` which results in values y, \xed \xf4 \x07. Are these byte values?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Strings are represented by [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values (UTF-8 to be precise) in computer. If you want to xor the plaintext character and keystream, I did recommend you to convert it into range of 26.

E.g. ***ord('a') is 97***  & ***ord('b') is 98*** in ASCII

```
ord('a') ^ ord('b') = 97 ^ 98 = 3
Note: 3 in ASCII is not an alphabet
a-z lies in range 97 - 122
A-Z lies in range 65 - 100
```

Try converting them into range of 26 first (using ord('a') for lowercase and ord('A') for uppercase as modulo). Generating **cipher - Step 1**:

```
ord('a') % 97 = 0
ord('b') % 97 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
```

Now, add the previous result ***1*** to ord('a') and then convert it into character. Generating **cipher - Step 2**:

```
chr( ord('a') + 1 ) = chr( 97 + 1 ) = chr( 98 ) = 'b'
```

Similarly, you can reverse the process to **decipher**.

***P.S.*** I am not aware of the Ciphersaber algorithm.